# Read Session Value In .Net Core Web Api

Tags: session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Web api when a user login successfully I set session with some values like

```
  HttpContext.Session.SetObject("CurrentUserID", user.Id);
                HttpContext.Session.SetObject("CurrentUserRoles",user.Roles);
```

and just return token and some values to save in cookie

```
  return Ok(new
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Username = user.UserName,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    Token = tokenString,
                    role = user.Roles
                });
```

But when the client hit api action which has this line

```
  List<string> userRolesList = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<List<string>>("CurrentUserRoles");
```

Then always get null value even I have added session inside Startup >Configure

like

```
 app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

and ConfigureService also

```
 services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 * 60);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

but does work still... Please help.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Sessions are fake state, enabled by both a server-side and client-side component. The client-side component is a cookie: specifically a `Set-Cookie` response header. In order for the session to be restored on the next request, the value of this `Set-Cookie` response header must be sent back via the `Cookie` request header *with each request*. A web browser (the client) will do all this automatically, including persisting the cookie locally. However, a thin client like `HttpClient`, Postman, etc. *will not*. You would need to independently persist the cookie from the response header and then attach it to each request via the `Cookie` header in order to maintain the session between requests.

That said, this is a major reason why APIs typically do not, and honestly *should* not make use of sessions. It's simply a pattern that doesn't make much sense in an API context, and only adds a potential point of failure, since clients must pay attention to the cookie headers, and take manual actions to handle the cookies.